# Condensing repeating code in php

Tags: php

So, I have following repeating code with different values:

```
<select placeholder="Any Max number" name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
    <option <?php selected('50000000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="50000000"><?php _e('No Max', 'my_site') ?></option>
    <option <?php selected('25000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="25000">25,000</option>
    <option <?php selected('50000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="50000">50,000</option>
    <option <?php selected('75000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="75000">75,000</option>
    <option <?php selected('100000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="100000">100,000</option>
</select>
```

As you can see the options are very similar and only increasing by `25,000` from the first one except the first one.

Is there a way to condense these codes? The number actually goes all the way up to `10,000,000` and there are over `38 similar codes` except the numeric value.

These feels like an un-efficient way of coding.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: yes there is a way, you make an array and then a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    <select placeholder="Any Max number" name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
    <option <?php selected('50000000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="50000000"><?php _e('No Max', 'my_site') ?></option>
<?php
        for($i=25000; $i<=1000000; $i+=25000) {
            echo '<option '. selected($i, isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : '') . ' value='.$i.'>'.number_format($i, 0).'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<select placeholder="Any Max number" name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
<option <?php selected('50000000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="50000000"><?php _e('No Max', 'my_site') ?></option>
<option <?php selected('25000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="25000">25,000</option>
<option <?php selected('50000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="50000">50,000</option>
<option <?php selected('75000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="75000">75,000</option>
<option <?php selected('100000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : ''); ?> value="100000">100,000</option>
```

into something like

```
<?php
 $opts = array(
    50000000 => _e('No Max', 'my_site'),
    25000 => '25,000',
    50000 => '50,000',
    ...
  );
?>


   <select placeholder="Any Max number" name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
    <?php  if( $_POST['sp_maxprice'] == $value ) {
               $selected = 'selected="selected"';
           }else{
               $selected = '';
          }
        foreach( $opts as $value => $caption ){

    ?>
      <option  value="<?php echo $value; ?>" $selected ><?php echo $caption; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select placeholder="Any Max Price" name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
<?php
$val = 25000;
do {
    echo '<option '. selected('50000000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : '') .' value="50000000">'. _e('No Max', 'my_site') .'</option>';
} while ($val < 100000){
    echo '<option '. selected($val, isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : '') .' value="'. $val .'">'. $val .'</option>';
    $val = $val + 25000;
}
?>
</select>
```

this may fulfil :)

Comment: what about this? <?php _e('No Max', 'my_site') ?>  and what is this? selected('50000000', isset($_GET['sp_maxprice']) ? $_GET['sp_maxprice'] : '') ~ selected is a function?